# Mysql Hosting requirements vtiger

Tags: mysql, vtiger

I want to acquire a hosting service to migrate my vtiger system that is in another hosting. My worry is that I want that the times of response for the end user of the vtiger system be fast. My questions are

1) What set "X" of parameters (beyond the [system requirements](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/System_Requirements) of vtiger for installation) I need to show to the new hosting provider of my actual system to ensure that they can support my system with very fast response time for the mysql queries of my vtiger system?

2) In relation to the last question what tool can I use to get "X"?

Comment: 1. they are marketers and sales people, they will promise the world. 2. a credit card

Comment: Please take the [tour](/tour) to learn what type of questions are acceptable.

Comment: @MartinBean do you know what subforum of stack exchange communities support my question?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL required for vtiger

1. MySQL 5.1+
2. storage_engine = InnoDB
3. local_file = On
4. sql_mode = empty (or NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION) for MySQL